How to show nifty Sensex values on a Django website
I am new to web development and I want to make a contribution to Django based repo where the news web site shows dynamically updating nifty Sensex values. Please tell me how to do it without registering to any web site; is it possible?
I tried looking for few web sites but since I am very new, any help would be appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
